# Chainlink External Adapter [Request failed with status code 400]

Tags: node.js, curl, chainlink

I'm trying to learn chainlink external adapters and am new to it all.

Would it be possible to get help with the following?
My adapter code is not working and telling me I'm using invalid parameters.

Im trying to hit the following API on coinpaprika:

https://api.coinpaprika.com/v1/price-converter?base_currency_id=link-chainlink&quote_currency_id=usdt-tether&amount=1

Here is my adapter code in nodejs

```
const customError = (data) => {
  if (data.Response === 'Error') return true
  return false
}

const customParams = {
  base: ['base', 'from', 'coin'],
  quote: ['quote', 'to', 'market'],
  amount: ['amount', 'qty', 'num'],
  endpoint: false
}

const createRequest = (input, callback) => {
  const validator = new Validator(callback, input, customParams)
  const jobRunID = validator.validated.id
  const endpoint = validator.validated.data.endpoint || 'price-converter'
  const url = `https://api.coinpaprika.com/v1/${endpoint}`
  const base_currency_id = validator.validated.data.base.toUpperCase()
  const quote_currency_id = validator.validated.data.quote.toUpperCase()
  const amount = validator.validated.data.amount.toUpperCase()


  const params = {
    base_currency_id,
    quote_currency_id,
    amount
  }

  const config = {
    url,
    params
  }

  Requester.request(config, customError)
    .then(response => {
      response.data.result = Requester.validateResultNumber(response.data, [amount])
      callback(response.status, Requester.success(jobRunID, response))
    })
    .catch(error => {
      callback(500, Requester.errored(jobRunID, error))
    })
}
```

Here is my CURL call:

`curl -X POST -H "content-type:application/json" "http://localhost:8080/" --data '{ "id": 0, "data": { "base": "chainlink", "quote": "usdt-tether","amount": "1" } }'`

This is the server error output im getting

```
  id: 0,
  data: { base: 'chainlink', quote: 'usdt-tether', amount: '1' }
}
{"message":"Caught error. Retrying: \"Request failed with status code 400\"","level":"warn","timestamp":"2021-07-25T09:06:44.560Z"}
{"message":"Caught error. Retrying: \"Request failed with status code 400\"","level":"warn","timestamp":"2021-07-25T09:06:45.696Z"}
{"message":"Could not reach endpoint: \"Request failed with status code 400\"","level":"error","timestamp":"2021-07-25T09:06:45.800Z"}
Result:  {
  jobRunID: 0,
  status: 'errored',
  error: AdapterError: AdapterError: Request failed with status code 400
      at Function.errored (/Users/xxxx/CL-EA-NodeJS-Template/node_modules/@chainlink/external-adapter/src/requester.js:90:14)
      at /Users/pocondui/CL-EA-NodeJS-Template/index.js:42:31
      at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5),
  statusCode: 500
```

> > UPDATE

looks like i was using the wrong CURL parameter, should be *link-chainlink* and not chainlink

```
POST Data:  {
  id: 0,
  data: { from: 'link-chainlink', to: 'usdt-tether', qty: '1' }
}
{"message":"Received response: {\"base_currency_id\":\"link-chainlink\",\"base_currency_name\":\"Chainlink\",\"base_price_last_updated\":\"2021-07-25T10:40:07Z\",\"quote_currency_id\":\"usdt-tether\",\"quote_currency_name\":\"Tether\",\"quote_price_last_updated\":\"2021-07-25T10:40:07Z\",\"amount\":1,\"price\":16.917664107956217}","level":"info","timestamp":"2021-07-25T10:41:07.797Z"}
{"message":"Result could not be found in path","level":"error","timestamp":"2021-07-25T10:41:07.797Z"}
Result:  {
  jobRunID: 0,
  status: 'errored',
  error: AdapterError: AdapterError: Result could not be found in path
      at Function.errored (/Users/pocondui/CL-EA-NodeJS-Template/node_modules/@chainlink/external-adapter/src/requester.js:90:14)
      at /Users/pocondui/CL-EA-NodeJS-Template/index.js:42:31
      at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5),
  statusCode: 500
```

Now i need to figure out how to pass the result correctly

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it.  2 issues were passing wrong parameter and the result was wrong

changed it to:

```
      response.data.result = Requester.validateResultNumber(response.data, ['price'])
```